# submit() Not yet implemented in appium

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I have a sanity where I enter a browser, sending a value to the url field in order to view the web page.
For example, if I click on the url web element, clear its value, and set it with a new value then I want to navigate to the new url. I use the method `submit()` in order to achieve it but I get an error: Not yet implemented.
This is the code:

```
    urlField.click();
    urlField.clear();
    urlField.sendKeys(url);
    urlField.submit();
```

Any idea how can I navigate to the new url?
Seeking help : http://appium.io/get-involved.html
Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for code writing services.

Comment: If that was aimed at me, I didn't vote. But you really should phrase yourself better than posting a "get-involved" link.

Comment: All I did was copying the error from the log. The link was part of the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`submit()` is not supported in Appium. You can use the following:

```
driver.pressKeyCode(66); //(66 is for ENTER)
```

according to the new release Java-client version 3.2.0